# Allocate less memory to processes to load a 6.8 GB dataset into R running on 8 GB machine

Tags: memory-usage

My idle system (64bit Ubuntu GNOME 15.10) uses around 2.5 GB RAM after restart, i.e. there's no running program launched by me. None of the applications I installed starts on startup. Which system processes can I safely kill or allocate less memory to in order to save around 7 GB of my 8 GB for `R`?

Answer (score 0):

After restart immediately launch the terminal and issue the command

```
free -m
```

Then look at values in the second row(-/+ buffers/cache:). Under second column(used) you'll see the actual RAM consumption of your system.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably find most of the memory in use is in the buffer cache. The default configuration for Linux is to cache file data in memory when memory is available.  When memory pressure increases (that is, more applications demand memory) then the data in the cache is discarded in an orderly manner if it is not dirty or flushed (written) to disk if it is dirty.

Accounting for the rest of memory that is in use by applications is a little bit tricky as applications share memory when using shared libraries and shared memory mappings.  You can use tools like "smemstat" to see how much memory is being used by processes:

```
sudo apt-get install smemstat
smemstat
```

The USS column reports the Unique Set Size (unshared memory), the PSS column reports the Proportional Set Size (proportion of shared memory) and the RSS column reports the Resident Set Size (non-swapped physical memory) used by each process.

The /proc/meminfo file also can be used to see how memory is being utilized, use:

```
cat /proc/meminfo
```

For information on all the fields, please refer to the [Linux Kernel Documentation on the /proc interfaces](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt).

If you application needs a lot of memory, the kernel will page out or drop unused pages from other processes, so you may not need to kill processes to give you the memory your require for your application.  As long as you have enough physical memory free for your application + kernel + active pages of other running processes your should see the system run without too much swap activity. Use can use tools such as vmstat to see the swap in (si) and swap out (so) activity to double check this:

```
vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0  45324  54252 147664 2897152    1    1    71    82   27  134  9  2 89  0  0
 3  0  45324  49924 147664 2902744    0    0   108     0 1570 7570 29  2 69  0  0
```